# What is the default Escalation Threshold for Microsoft SQL server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

What is the default table Escalation Threshold for Microsoft SQL server 2014.

Note: on SQL 2008 and 2012 was 5000 and there is reference, but I cant find any reference for 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the MSDN has mentioned at the top itself that this applies to the 2008 and higher versions. So it would be **5000** for *2014* version as well.

**Applies to: SQL Server 2008 R2 and higher versions.**

From the [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx)

> When the Database Engine checks for possible escalations at every 1250
>   newly acquired locks, a lock escalation will occur if and only if a
>   Transact-SQL statement has acquired at least 5000 locks on a single
>   reference of a table. Lock escalation is triggered when a Transact-SQL
>   statement acquires at least 5,000 locks on a single reference of a
>   table. For example, lock escalation is not triggered if a statement
>   acquires 3,000 locks in one index and 3,000 locks in another index of
>   the same table. Similarly, lock escalation is not triggered if a
>   statement has a self join on a table, and each reference to the table
>   only acquires 3,000 locks in the table.